# How to restart MySQL server? The restart button is disabled

Tags: mysql

I can not restart mysql server. I read many answers from here, but didn't solve my problem. whether I try doing it by command prompt or windows +R; start, stop and restart buttons are disabled. I can not use them to restart.  Is there any other way?
Thanks all

Comment: What button? Of which program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restart MySQL server on Windows you can try with `services.msc`
from `cmd` by open the `Run` window by using the `Windows+R` keyboard. Under service local select `MySQL` than click on restart. see on image.[image]

[You can check this reference](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adminsitration/restart-mysql/)